# Patient Queue/Token Management System Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named **tblTokenQueue** as shown below

```
CouponNo   Status      Sequence
A101      Completed       1
A102      Completed       2
A103      Completed       3
A104      Serving         4
A105      Pending         5
A106      Pending         6
A107      Pending         7
A108      Pending         8
A109      Pending         9
A110      Pending         10
A111      Pending         11
A112      Pending         12
A113      Pending         13
A114      Pending         14
A115      Pending         15
```

I have a case where tokens can be put on hold. Hospital says when we resume hold tokens it should be placed after 3 tokens from the currently serving token. In our example lets say A105 and A106 are put on hold. I will assign a sequence no -99 for all hold tokens. Then the table becomes

```
CouponNo   Status      Sequence
    A101      Completed       1
    A102      Completed       2
    A103      Completed       3
    A104      Serving         4
    A105      Hold           -99
    A106      Hold           -99
    A107      Pending         5
    A108      Pending         6
    A109      Pending         7
    A110      Pending         8
    A111      Pending         9
    A112      Pending         10
    A113      Pending         11
    A114      Pending         12
    A115      Pending         13
```

And when we resume both, i want the table like below. Which means resumed tokens should be placed after 3 tokens of currently serving token.

```
CouponNo   Status      Sequence
    A101      Completed       1
    A102      Completed       2
    A103      Completed       3
    A104      Serving         4
  **A105      Pending         8**
  **A106      Pending         9**            
    A107      Pending         5
    A108      Pending         6
    A109      Pending         7
    A110      Pending         10
    A111      Pending         11
    A112      Pending         12
    A113      Pending         13
    A114      Pending         14
    A115      Pending         15
```

When we hold the token and resume following conditions may happen

1. There is one customer being served. in the example quoted above its 
   A104 and token A105 is resumed.
2. Lets say currently served token is A105 and i put him on hold. next
   token is A106 and i put him on hold too. And immediately i want to
   resume A105 back to pending without serving any other one. In this
   case no one is getting "served"
3. Token A101 is the first token and i put him on hold and want to
   resume back. at this stage no one is getting served and no completed
   tokens.
4. Now lets say token A114 is on hold (As per our example above) and
   want to resume. Only one token is left after him. So there is no
   point in adding 3 to his sequence number.

**I have created two procedures**

for putting token on hold

```
create procedure TokenHoldProc(@TokenNo varchar(10))
        as
        begin
        update tblTokenQueue set TokenSequence='-99',TokenStatus='Hold' where TokenNo=@TokenNo
        end
```

for resuming token

```
create procedure TokenResumeProc(@TokenNo varchar(10),@TokenPushCount int)
    as
    begin
    declare @ServingPosition int
    select  @ServingPosition=TokenSequence from tblTokenQueue where TokenStatus='Serving'
        if (@ServingPosition is null) --if no one is getting served at present 
            begin
            select @ServingPosition=TokenSequence from tblTokenQueue where TokenStatus='Completed'
                if (@ServingPosition is  null)  --if its the first token
                    update tblTokenQueue set TokenSequence = 1 where TokenNo=@TokenNo;
                    else
                    begin
                        update tblTokenQueue set TokenSequence = TokenSequence + 1 where TokenSequence >=@ServingPosition+(@TokenPushCount+1);
                        update tblTokenQueue set TokenSequence = @ServingPosition+(@TokenPushCount+1),TokenStatus='Pending'  where TokenNo=@TokenNo;
                    end
                    end
        else
        begin
            update tblTokenQueue set TokenSequence = TokenSequence + 1 where TokenSequence >=@ServingPosition+(@TokenPushCount+1);
            update tblTokenQueue set TokenSequence = @ServingPosition+(@TokenPushCount+1),TokenStatus='Pending'  where TokenNo=@TokenNo;
        end
    end
```

As per these procedures first 3 cases will be met. But there are 2 issues

1. case number 4 .
2. if i want to resume 2 hold tokens one after the other it will generate same sequence number for both

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you need a maximum in this part:

```
select @ServingPosition=max(TokenSequence) from tblTokenQueue where TokenStatus='Completed'
```

For your 2nd problem, I would need to know more.  If you take a batch of tokens off hold at the same time, then maybe you could just process them in reverse order.  If they aren't a batch then what is happening is meeting the criteria presented.  One possibility I see to help this issue is to add a new Status called "Resumed".  You can create a special case where resumed coupons have higher priority and aren't included in the "plus 3" calculation.

I don't quite think I understand your first issue with case #4.  But perhaps it's as simple as grabbing the max sequence and using it in your set statement --

```
case when @ServingPosition+(@TokenPushCount+1) > @MaxSequence + 1 then @MaxSequence + 1 else @ServingPosition+(@TokenPushCount+1) end
```